# Binary Bomb Phase 5 - lookup table translation -> string compare

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, binary-bomb

I have been working on a Binary Bomb for school, and I am absolutely lost in Phase 5. The object of the assignment is to dissemble the code and find a string, which I have found to be "flyers" and reverse engineer it to have the same numerical value as "flyers" does. However, I have spent the last 3-4 hours trying to find out how to do this? You don't have to give answers, but PLEASE help me understand what I need to do. Here is the disassembled code using gdb:

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
0x08048d88 <+0>:    push   %ebx
0x08048d89 <+1>:    sub    $0x28,%esp
0x08048d8c <+4>:    mov    0x30(%esp),%ebx
0x08048d90 <+8>:    mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
0x08048d96 <+14>:    mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)
0x08048d9a <+18>:    xor    %eax,%eax
0x08048d9c <+20>:    mov    %ebx,(%esp)
0x08048d9f <+23>:    call   0x804902b <string_length>
0x08048da4 <+28>:    cmp    $0x6,%eax
0x08048da7 <+31>:    je     0x8048dae <phase_5+38>
0x08048da9 <+33>:    call   0x804934c <explode_bomb>
0x08048dae <+38>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x08048db3 <+43>:    movsbl (%ebx,%eax,1),%edx
0x08048db7 <+47>:    and    $0xf,%edx
0x08048dba <+50>:    movzbl 0x804a4b8(%edx),%edx
0x08048dc1 <+57>:    mov    %dl,0x15(%esp,%eax,1)
0x08048dc5 <+61>:    add    $0x1,%eax
0x08048dc8 <+64>:    cmp    $0x6,%eax
0x08048dcb <+67>:    jne    0x8048db3 <phase_5+43>
0x08048dcd <+69>:    movb   $0x0,0x1b(%esp)
0x08048dd2 <+74>:    movl   $0x804a48e,0x4(%esp)
0x08048dda <+82>:    lea    0x15(%esp),%eax
0x08048dde <+86>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048de1 <+89>:    call   0x8049044 <strings_not_equal>
0x08048de6 <+94>:    test   %eax,%eax
0x08048de8 <+96>:    je     0x8048def <phase_5+103>
0x08048dea <+98>:    call   0x804934c <explode_bomb>
0x08048def <+103>:    mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
0x08048df3 <+107>:    xor    %gs:0x14,%eax
0x08048dfa <+114>:    je     0x8048e05 <phase_5+125>
0x08048dfc <+116>:    lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
0x08048e00 <+120>:    call   0x8048810 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
0x08048e05 <+125>:    add    $0x28,%esp
0x08048e08 <+128>:    pop    %ebx
0x08048e09 <+129>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: [Bomb Lab phase 5: 6 char string substitution lookup table, strings\_not\_equal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22032475) has a C version reverse-engineered from the asm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't quite clear what `flyers` is, I assume that is one correct input and you have to find others.

The important part is at `<+47>` and `<+50>`. It is using a 16-byte lookup table to transform the input string. The code is basically doing:

```
for(int i = 0; i != 6; i += 1) output[i] = table[input[i] & 0xf];
```

It's obvious that any characters that share the low 4 bits will produce the same output (even if the values in the lookup table are unique). For example, the first character `f` has ascii code 0x66, so it is mapped by table entry 0x06. The same applies to any character with 0x06 as low 4 bits, such as `&` (0x26), `6` (0x36), `F` (0x46), `V` (0x56), `v` (0x76). You can replace `f` with any of those (non-printable and full 8 bit values omitted for brevity). You can work out the equivalences for the other letters similarly.

If `flyers` instead is the required output, then you have to examine the contents of the lookup table at address `0x804a4b8` and provide input string with the correct letters that map to the expected output.