# Bomb lab phase 5 - 6 char string, movzbl load, and $0xf, %ecx, and index an array with that?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, binary-bomb

Alright so this is the ever so popular bomb lab and I am currently on phase 5 and I'm only stuck on two lines. Here's the assembly code:

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x08048e29 <+0>: push   %ebx
   0x08048e2a <+1>: sub    $0x18,%esp
   0x08048e2d <+4>: mov    0x20(%esp),%ebx
   0x08048e31 <+8>: mov    %ebx,(%esp)
   0x08048e34 <+11>:    call   0x804908b <string_length>
   0x08048e39 <+16>:    cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x08048e3c <+19>:    je     0x8048e43 <phase_5+26>
   0x08048e3e <+21>:    call   0x80493a5 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e43 <+26>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x08048e48 <+31>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048e4d <+36>:    movzbl (%ebx,%eax,1),%ecx
   0x08048e51 <+40>:    and    $0xf,%ecx
   0x08048e54 <+43>:    add    0x804a4a0(,%ecx,4),%edx
   0x08048e5b <+50>:    add    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048e5e <+53>:    cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x08048e61 <+56>:    jne    0x8048e4d <phase_5+36>
=> 0x08048e63 <+58>:    cmp    $0x42,%edx
   0x08048e66 <+61>:    je     0x8048e6d <phase_5+68>
   0x08048e68 <+63>:    call   0x80493a5 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e6d <+68>:    add    $0x18,%esp
   0x08048e70 <+71>:    pop    %ebx
   0x08048e71 <+72>:    ret    
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
End of assembler dump.
```

Here's a barebones look when I run it through a decompiler:

```
void phase_5(__size8 *param1) {
__size32 eax; // r24
int eax_1; // r24{48}
unsigned int ecx; // r25
__size32 edx; // r26
eax = string_length(param1);
if (eax != 6) {
explode_bomb();
}
edx = 0;
eax = 0;
do {
eax_1 = eax;
ecx = *(unsigned char*)(param1 + eax_1);
edx += array.3142[(ecx & 0xf)];
eax = eax_1 + 1;
} while (eax_1 + 1 != 6);
if (edx != 66) {
explode_bomb();
}
return;
}
```

So the general synopsis of this phase is that the string input needs to be 6 characters, then it goes through a do while loop where it takes the string and turns it into a number through its algorithm and then compares it if it's 66 at the end. My questions is what do these two lines do:

ecx = *(unsigned char*)(param1 + eax_1);
edx += array.3142[(ecx & 0xf)];

More specifically the first one. The second line &s the value of the first line with 15 which essentially gives the last 4 bits of ecx but what does adding the string (param1) with the loop counter (eax_1) do? Also is this the line that converts each character in the string into a number? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Defusing a Binary Bomb: phase\_5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40950347) has another good description in words of how to pick a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what does adding the string (param1) with the loop counter (eax_1) do?

That's just array indexing. It gives you the address of the appropriate character. `ecx = *(unsigned char*)(param1 + eax_1)` is basically `ecx = param1[eax_1]`.

As you say, the code loops through all 6 letters, keeps the low 4 bits of the ascii code and uses that to index a hardcoded lookup table. The selected values from said lookup table are summed up, and that's your result which has to be `0x42`.

Comment: Ah I see, so how come when I run "kkkkkk" it gives me 30 instead of 66? If I did the math out, shouldn't it just be 11 + 11 + 11... 6 times since the binary for k ends in 1011 which is 11.

Comment: Oh wait I think I misunderstood, you mean they have their own ascii code in array.3142, meaning that they have their own numerical values for letters?

Comment: other than finding these keys the long way could you tell me where they are storing the table in the assembly language ^.^

Comment: Hey I got it defused! As usual thanks for the help Jester, but could you still tell me where I could find their table in the assembly code just for future notice.

Comment: Since you have `add    0x804a4a0(,%ecx,4),%edx` the table is at address `0x804a4a0` and it has length 16. So you should be able to print it using `x/16 0x804a4a0`.