# Bomb lab phase 5

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-64

I've tried to figure out what's happening. The only thing that I understand now is that my answer should be exactly 6 symbols. Could you please help me?

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x00000000004010f3 <+0>: push   %rbx
   0x00000000004010f4 <+1>: mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x00000000004010f7 <+4>: callq  0x40133b <string_length>
   0x00000000004010fc <+9>: cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x00000000004010ff <+12>:    je     0x401106 <phase_5+19>
   0x0000000000401101 <+14>:    callq  0x401659 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401106 <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040110b <+24>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x0000000000401110 <+29>:    movsbl (%rbx,%rax,1),%ecx
   0x0000000000401114 <+33>:    and    $0xf,%ecx
   0x0000000000401117 <+36>:    add    0x4028a0(,%rcx,4),%edx
   0x000000000040111e <+43>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x0000000000401122 <+47>:    cmp    $0x6,%rax
   0x0000000000401126 <+51>:    jne    0x401110 <phase_5+29>
   0x0000000000401128 <+53>:    cmp    $0x2e,%edx
   0x000000000040112b <+56>:    je     0x401132 <phase_5+63>
   0x000000000040112d <+58>:    callq  0x401659 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401132 <+63>:    pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000401133 <+64>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: It might help if you provide context -at least a link, but preferred editing your question- about the problem. I have no idea what is "Bomb lab phase 5", and to be honest I would like to not google it. ;)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but I hope you can figure out the small differences.

Comment: @Jester, you replied in another thread that I can print the keys. So I did, but I'm not getting how to interpret the results.

      `(gdb) x/16 0x4028a0
      0x4028a0 <array.3317>: 2 10 6 1
      0x4028b0 <array.3317+16>: 12 16 9 3
      0x4028c0 <array.3317+32>: 4 7 14 5
      0x4028d0 <array.3317+48>: 11 8 15 13`

Comment: @GáborBakos, the task is nearly the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543031/decoding-assembly-language-bomb-lab-phase-5/30829908#30829908. I cannot understand how to run through decompiler and find the string.