# Bomb Lab Assignment Phase 5 - Writing Its C Equivalent

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, position-independent-code

I am trying to solve a slightly modified Bomb Lab problem for my Computer Architecture class. I'm supposed to write the C equivalent for the functions, but got stuck in Phase 5. It's very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543031/bomb-lab-phase-5-6-char-string-movzbl-load-and-0xf-ecx-and-index-an-arra) and I have indeed figured out what the function does for the most part.

```
    105b:   56                      push   %esi
    105c:   53                      push   %ebx
    105d:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
    1060:   e8 6b fa ff ff          call   ad0 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
    1065:   81 c3 fb 3e 00 00       add    $0x3efb,%ebx
    106b:   8b 74 24 1c             mov    0x1c(%esp),%esi
    106f:   56                      push   %esi
    1070:   e8 bf 02 00 00          call   1334 <string_length>
    1075:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
    1078:   83 f8 06                cmp    $0x6,%eax
    107b:   75 2e                   jne    10ab <phase_5+0x50>
    107d:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
    107f:   83 c6 06                add    $0x6,%esi
    1082:   b9 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ecx
    1087:   0f b6 10                movzbl (%eax),%edx
    108a:   83 e2 0f                and    $0xf,%edx
    108d:   03 8c 93 00 da ff ff    add    -0x2600(%ebx,%edx,4),%ecx
    1094:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
    1097:   39 f0                   cmp    %esi,%eax
    1099:   75 ec                   jne    1087 <phase_5+0x2c>
    109b:   83 f9 34                cmp    $0x34,%ecx
    109e:   74 05                   je     10a5 <phase_5+0x4a>
    10a0:   e8 38 05 00 00          call   15dd <explode_bomb>
    10a5:   83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp
    10a8:   5b                      pop    %ebx
    10a9:   5e                      pop    %esi
    10aa:   c3                      ret    
    10ab:   e8 2d 05 00 00          call   15dd <explode_bomb>
    10b0:   eb cb                   jmp    107d <phase_5+0x22>
```

It's a function that accepts a string of 6 characters (bomb explodes if it doesn't) and does some form of looping algorithm that produces a number. At the end, if the result of the loop does not equal 52 (0x34), the bomb explodes once again. However, I couldn't understand a certain part of the code:

```
    108d:   03 8c 93 00 da ff ff    add    -0x2600(%ebx,%edx,4),%ecx
```

Apparently, it offsets the number you've obtained by masking the ASCII equivalent of each character in the string by some unknown algorithm. For now, I've made a table of offsets for each character and managed to get an accepted string, `aaaabb`, but I would like to know what the C equivalent of the code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in Jester's answer, it's indexing an array.  `ecx += table[edx]`, for `static int table[];`  The EDX index is scaled by 4 in the addressing mode because `sizeof(int)` is 4; asm needs byte offsets, C indexing uses element offsets.

---

`-0x2600 + %ebx` is a static array, same as `0x804a4a0` in the linked question.  But it's harder to find in static disassembly because **whoever created this executable annoyingly compiled it as 32-bit PIE (position-independent executable).**

32-bit PIC / PIE sucks because PC-relative addressing was new with x86-64, so this is needlessly more complicated to reverse engineer.

It gets the GOT (Global Offset Table) address into EBX:  First `call __x86.get_pc_thunk.bx` returns its return address in EBX, i.e. `0x1065` with the placeholder addresses you got from `objdump -d`.  Then `add    $0x3efb,%ebx` adds the offset from that location to the GOT.

Then static data is addressed relative to the GOT base (in EBX in this case).  Pain the ass to follow that vs. an absolute address.  You could just single-step in a debugger in a running process, after the kernel's program-loader maps the code to some virtual address (other than `0x1000`).

Or do it manually: `0x1065 + 0x3efb` = GOT base (EBX) of `0x4f60`.
**`0x4f60-0x2600` is the lookup table array start: `0x2960` (if you were using `objdump -D` to dump the data sections as well).**  You might be able to use that address in GDB (*before* `start` or `run`) with an `x` command to dump the table in a convenient format other than fake disassembly of data as code from objdump.

The actual address in a running process will be that plus some multiple of 4096 (0x1000).

Comment: So, does it essentially use the table of offset values I've mentioned earlier? In my function, am I supposed to hard-code said table, or simply retrieve its values from main?

Comment: The table of 32-bit integers isn't a table of *offset* values, just values that get summed.  The offsets into the table are from the low bits of the string that main passes as an arg.  The table is in static storage, and private to this function, so `static int table[] = {...}` inside the function would be the correct way to define it in a C version that matches the asm.  main doesn't know about it.