# Bomb Lab Phase_5 string length

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly

i'm fighting since 2 days with this task in the Bomb_lab.
As long as I understood, an input of 7 (char) is required. The function "string_length" has nothing interesting, it just checks for the length of the input.

The rest of the code seems to be similar to the one showed [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543031/bomb-lab-phase-5-6-char-string-movzbl-load-and-0xf-ecx-and-index-an-arra)

But I still can't how should my string look like to match the final condition (I only know from the last compare that it should be egual to $0x46)

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

```
0000000000400f58 <phase_5>:
  400f58:   53                      push   %rbx
  400f59:   48 89 fb                mov    %rdi,%rbx
  400f5c:   e8 20 12 00 00          callq  402181 <phase_init>
  400f61:   48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
  400f64:   e8 2f 02 00 00          callq  401198 <string_length>
  400f69:   83 f8 07                cmp    $0x7,%eax  // string has to be longer than 7
  400f6c:   74 05                   je     400f73 <phase_5+0x1b>
  400f6e:   e8 79 04 00 00          callq  4013ec <explode_bomb>
  400f73:   48 89 d8                mov    %rbx,%rax
  400f76:   48 8d 7b 07             lea    0x7(%rbx),%rdi
  400f7a:   b9 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ecx
  400f7f:   0f b6 10                movzbl (%rax),%edx
  400f82:   83 e2 0f                and    $0xf,%edx
  400f85:   03 0c 95 a0 25 40 00    add    0x4025a0(,%rdx,4),%ecx
  400f8c:   48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
  400f90:   48 39 f8                cmp    %rdi,%rax
  400f93:   75 ea                   jne    400f7f <phase_5+0x27>
  400f95:   83 f9 46                cmp    $0x46,%ecx
  400f98:   74 05                   je     400f9f <phase_5+0x47>
  400f9a:   e8 4d 04 00 00          callq  4013ec <explode_bomb>
  400f9f:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  400fa0:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: Well, it's comparing `ecx` against 0x46, so you need to figure out how `ecx` gets the value it has when that comparison occurs. And that happens in the loop from 400f7f..400f93. So you needs to analyze what the loop does.

Comment: Information about how the array at 0x4025a0 is initialized seems to be missing from your question. Also, the comment `string has to be longer than 7` is incorrect; the length of the string has to be _exactly_ 7.

Comment: Yes it was actually a typo. Thank you for your help!