# Need help understanding Binary Bomb Phase_5

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

So I have been working through this binary bomb lab, and phase_5 is the only part I do not really understand. I have solved it, but there are a few lines that I hope someone can help me with.

```
   0x08048db1 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048db2 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048db4 <+3>: push   %ebx
=> 0x08048db5 <+4>: sub    $0x14,%esp
   0x08048db8 <+7>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%ebx
   0x08048dbb <+10>:    mov    %ebx,(%esp)
   0x08048dbe <+13>:    call   0x8049009 <string_length>
   0x08048dc3 <+18>:    cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x08048dc6 <+21>:    je     0x8048dcd <phase_5+28>
   0x08048dc8 <+23>:    call   0x8049231 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048dcd <+28>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x08048dd2 <+33>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048dd7 <+38>:    mov    (%ebx,%eax,1),%cl
   0x08048dda <+41>:    and    $0xf,%ecx
   0x08048ddd <+44>:    add    0x804a460(,%ecx,4),%edx
   0x08048de4 <+51>:    inc    %eax
   0x08048de5 <+52>:    cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x08048de8 <+55>:    jne    0x8048dd7 <phase_5+38>
   0x08048dea <+57>:    cmp    $0x36,%edx
   0x08048ded <+60>:    je     0x8048df4 <phase_5+67>
   0x08048def <+62>:    call   0x8049231 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048df4 <+67>:    add    $0x14,%esp
   0x08048df7 <+70>:    pop    %ebx
   0x08048df8 <+71>:    pop    %ebp
   0x08048df9 <+72>:    ret
```

Here I'll explain how I came up with a solution. I realize I wrote a lot so if you wish to skip it I am having trouble understanding line <+44>.

It was pretty easy to see that the input was 6 characters, so I entered a random guess: "hither"

Moving to line 38 I see that %eax + %ebx is being moved into the %cl register, which as I understand it is the first 8 bytes if %ecx. I noticed that my string was stored in %ebx, so seeing as %eax is incremented from 0 to 5 while this line is being called I assumed that it is storing the decimal value of the ascii character at the %eax element of my string in %cl.

Moving to the next line that was correct. And-ing ecx with 0xf (0x1111) was putting a mask on and reducing %ecx down to the first 4 bytes, aka a number between 0 and 15.

Line 44 is where I got confused.

As I understand add, the line should set
%edx += %ecx*4 + value_at(0x804a460). When I inspected the 0x804a460 address it contained the value 2. For the first iteration of my loop masking the character "h" left me with the decimal number 8. So I assumed that edx would be set to 34, yet after that line it was set to 4.

So this line is increasing %edx 6 times based on the masked value of my character. Seeing the cmp on line 57 0x36 and %edx I knew at the end I needed to end up with 54.

The i, which was masked to 9, increased my edx by 7. The t, h and r increased my edx by 12, 16, and 6 respectively.

So given 54/6 = 9, and given I have no idea what this add line is doing, I decided to run another string through and see if I could find a masked character that increased my %edx by 9.

I looked at an ascii table and decided to put in: kwsqfm which when masked equals (11)(7)(3)(1)(6)(13) in decimal. I then just went through each step of the loop and checked how much each decimal value was increasing %edx.

To my pleasant surprise, f ended up increasing %edx by +9. So I simply put in "ffffff" as my password and defused the phase.

I'm not entirely satisfied with how I found this answer because of the "brute force" method I used. Even though there were really only 15 masked values to check I would rather understand what exactly is going on here.

Line <+44> is undoubtedly what is causing me trouble. If anyone could help me understand that add statement I would be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to SO oliver. hint: `0x804a460` is a table of 16 DWORDs. Also you are confused  about terminology, addressing modes and pointers in general. The code is really straightforward and easy, trace it on a paper with a test string. If something seems weird or even unusual check it again, there is nothing fancy with this code :)

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29543210/547981) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14651462/547981).

Comment: Thank you KNM241 & Jester! You've really put me back on track, much appreciated.